# keras で確率の偏った乱数を生成する

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras に手を出そうとしている者です。やりたいことのイメージはついてるのですが、どのようなキーワードでGoogleなどで検索をすればよいか、とっかかり自体がつかめないです。
以下を実現するプログラムはどのように作ればよいのでしょうか？
Googleで調べるにしてもどの様に調べればよいか判らないので、質問させていただきました。

### やりたいこと

- 学習データとして数字を使う
- 必ず **5つ** の乱数をカンマ区切りで出力するようにする
- 出力する乱数は、学習データに伴い偏りが出るようにする

### 例

最初の内は `(1,2,3,4,5)`のように１~5までの純粋な乱数を発生させる。しかし、学習データに「1」を学習させると、乱数の発生の際に「1」の発生率が高くなる。学習データに「99」の数字を学習させると、「99」の乱数も出力するようになる。

Comment: 「イカサマの乱数を5つ一気に生成する」プログラムよりも、「イカサマの乱数を1つ生成する」プログラムを5回実行するほうが考えやすいのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

学習データとして、複数の整数をリストに入れて、用意したとします。学習データはいくら大きくても問題ありません。

例1:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

例2:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]
```

このリストに入っている整数に従って（つまり、それぞれの数字の個数に出る確率が比例する）乱数を1つ生成する最も簡単な方法は、[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/random.html#random.choice)を使うことです。

```py
from random import choice

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]

print(choice(a))
```

ヒストグラムを描いてみると、実際に偏っていることが確認できます。

```py
from random import choice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]

numbers = [choice(a) for _ in range(15000)]

plt.hist(numbers, bins=np.arange(min(a), max(a) + 2) - 0.5, rwidth=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

あとは、これを5個まとめてカンマ区切りで出力すればよいことになります。例えば、次のプログラムでは 5個/回 × 10回 = 計50個 の乱数を出力しています。

```py
from random import choice

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]

for _ in range(10):
    numbers = [choice(a) for _ in range(5)]
    print(', '.join(str(n) for n in numbers))
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: なぜKerasなのか分かりませんが、とりあえず解答してみました。